# What is the best practice while renaming Django Models? [Database: MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite]

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, django-models

I really want to know what is the best practice that could be done while renaming `Django Models` and `Models Fields`. Is there are preferred method or we should directly rename and migrate each FIELD or MODEL inside Django. Whenever I rename my models an models fields it pops some error and `001initials` decencies error messages, what can I do.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to create a new field with the new name, copy the data from the old field into the new field, then remove the old field. The same can be applied to models.

Sometimes simply renaming a model or field will be fine with django, just be sure you have a db and code base backup before you make any changes.